# Euclidean Distance error in ArcMap 10.8.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, error-999999, euclidean

I'm a beginner in GIS.

I've trying to form a buffer for:

- a road layer and 3 others:
- rivers, villages and protected areas

in ArcMap using Euclidean Distance tool, but I'm getting an error when I set the cell size 30 or anything below 44 (my DEM cell size is 30). Also if I set the extent and mask in the Environment Settings, that number has to be above 45 as any size below 46 causes the same error.

I've made sure the coordinates are the same, changed file output direction, changed file name, disabled background processing, done repair geometry and... but still get the same error.

I should also note that setting a higher cell size than stated will fix the problem; also those 4 layers are vectors. Another interesting thing is using an older version of ArcGIS either 10.3 or 10.7 doesn't cause this error. It's the version where you can't choose another Distance Method like Geodesic or Planar.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: right, sorry about that. all of them are vectors, WGS_1984_UTM

Comment: You say you are trying to create a buffer around your data and you state that you inputs are vector, why not simply use the Buffer tool?

Comment: I've been told that combining the layers later in the project requires them to be either all raster or vector (also that I should decide the coordinate system and either they should be raster or vector based on my goal and before starting the project (practice here)), and there are rasters like DEM, Slope and Aspect that i need. though I'm not sure how it's all going to work out.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to state the version of ArcMap you *are* using.

Comment: You are getting a licensing error. You may need an advanced instead of a basic desktop license.

Comment: @Vince I added the version as well.

Comment: @enolan I don't see how it would work like that, I've used another file downloaded from Naturalearthdata and the cell size could be set to 0.13 and it would work fine.. though I tried a lower cell size and got the same error